# Algorithmic package in LaTeX

Tags: algorithms

I want to write the following algorithm in LaTeX:

```
 V <- AllUnigramsInTraining(D)
 N <- NumberOfTweets(D)
**for** each c ∈ C do
  Nc <- Number of tweets in Class c
  prior(c) <- [...] 
  Tweetsc <- All Tweets in class c
  **for** each term t ∈ V do
    Tct <- No. of times term t appeared in Tweetsc
  **end for**
  **for** each term t ∈ V do
    prob[t][c] <- [...] 
  **end for**
**end for**
```

I wrote the following code but it is not compiling properly. Can anybody help?

```
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $V\gets AllUnigramsInTraining(D)$ \\
\STATE $N\gets NumberOfTweets(D)$ \\
 \FOR each $c \in C$ \DO \\
  \STATE $N_c\gets Number of tweets in Class c$ \\
  \begin{equation}
    prior(c) = \frac{N_c}{N} \\
   \end{equation}
  \STATE $Tweets_c\gets = All Tweets in class c$ \\
  \FOR each term $t \in V$ \DO \\
    T_ct = No. of times term t appeared in Tweets_c \\
  \END
  \FOR each term $t \in V$ \DO \\
    \begin{equation}
     $prob[t][c] = \frac{T_ct}{\sum_^t'{T_ct'+ 1}} \\
    \end{equation}
  \END
\END
\end{algorithmic}
```

Comment: Your question at SO got migrated here and subsequently got merged with this one. You need to re-accept an answer now.

Comment: I now merged both your accounts together. This changed the displayed username of this question. Feel free to change the user name used on this site using your profile page.

Answer (score 13):

There is *so much* wrong there. You don't need `\\` at the end of lines for starters. You have an (unbalanced) inline math `$` inside of an equation. You have subscripts outside of math mode. Your sum notation has problems. I don't know what you want exactly, but this should at least give you output, whether it's exactly what you want... I don't know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $V\gets$ AllUnigramsInTraining($D$)
\STATE $N\gets$ NumberOfTweets($D$)
 \FORALL{$c \in C$}
  \STATE $N_c \gets$ Number of tweets in Class $c$
  \STATE \begin{equation}prior(c) = \frac{N_c}{N}\end{equation}
  \STATE $Tweets_c \gets $All Tweets in class $c$
  \FORALL{$t \in V$}
    \STATE $T_ct$ = No. of times term $t$ appeared in $Tweets_c$
  \ENDFOR
  \FORALL{$t \in V$}
    \STATE \begin{equation}prob[t][c] = \frac{T_ct}{\sum^{t'}T_ct'+ 1}\end{equation}
  \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` statements are missing brackets, and your equation blocks should be `\state` lines.

There are some good examples in the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode)